# Why onEach is not a suspend function but collect is?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I read somewhere that it's because onEach is not performing any proccessing based on the emitted values but it just alters them; But collect is likely to perform some asynchronous or heavy tasks on the collected values that may block the thread.

It doesn't seem correct to me; What if we are performing some heavy tasks on the values in the onEach function and it has the possibility to block the thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you confuse suspendability of the action performed in operators with the suspendability of the operator itself. Actions performed in `onEach` actually can suspend, as we can see in the function definition:

```kotlin
public fun <T> Flow<T>.onEach(action: suspend (T) -> Unit): Flow<T>
```

Please note: `action: suspend`.

The difference between `collect` and `onEach` is that when we call the `onEach`, then this call can't suspend. Which makes sense, because calling `onEach` doesn't do anything by itself. It only creates a new flow by appending an operator to the previous flow, but it doesn't process anything yet and immediately returns to the caller. `collect` suspends the caller until the flow is fully consumed.

Please see the documentation for [intermediate flow operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#intermediate-flow-operators):

> Flows can be transformed using operators, in the same way as you would transform collections and sequences. Intermediate operators are applied to an upstream flow and return a downstream flow. These operators are cold, just like flows are. A call to such an operator is not a suspending function itself. It works quickly, returning the definition of a new transformed flow.

And [terminal flow operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#terminal-flow-operators):

> Terminal operators on flows are suspending functions that start a collection of the flow. The collect operator is the most basic one, but there are other terminal operators, which can make it easier: